# Trigger child rerendering from another child component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on an app with a login page and a main page. In my main page, I have a component A that accepts a request and posts it to a nodejs server, which updates it on a database. Another component B fetches data from the database and displays it. I want to be able to rerender component B when component A's request has been returned with a response.

I understand that I can create a dummy state variable and pass it to B and pass a prop function to A to allow it to change it, but is there a more effective way of doing this?

Code for A's get request:

```
const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (vendor === "" || amount === "") {
    } else {
      const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/newpayment`, {
        vendor,
        amount,
      });
      // want to check res and rerender component B
    }

    setVendor("");
    setAmount("");
  };
```

Code for component B:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ComponentB= () => {
  const [payments, setPayments] = useState([]);

  const fetchPayments = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/paymentspending`);

    setPayments(res.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPayments();
  }, []);

  const onClick = async (id) => {
    await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/markpaid`, { id });
    fetchPayments();
  };

  const renderedPayments = Object.values(payments).map((payment) => {
    return (
      <div
        className="card"
        style={{ width: "100%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
        key={payment.id}
      >
        <div className="card-body">
          <h4>{payment.vendor}</h4>
          <h5>{payment.amount}</h5>
          <button
            className="btn btn-success"
            onClick={() => onClick(payment.id)}
          >
            Mark as Paid
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div className="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">{renderedPayments}</div>;
};

export default ComponentB;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to share the state between components:

1. [Lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).
2. Add the global store to the app, for example, [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/).

If it is a small app, lift the state. Use the Redux if it is a big project.